# Configuring Locales on Linux for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, locale, latin1

I'm having trouble getting a particular database set up and running. I'm trying to restore a postgreSQL dump I got from somebody else. I've tried a few methods to no avail.

1. Straight from pg_restore

   `pg_restore -C -d postgres --exit-on-error maggie_prod_20111221.dump.sql`
2. Creating the database and tablespace first

   `createdb -T template0 maggieprod -E LATIN1`

   SQL: `CREATE TABLESPACE magdat OWNER maggie LOCATION '/somewhere/magdat';`

   `pg_restore -v -d template1 maggie_prod_20110121.dump.sql`

Using the first method I get the following:

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:`

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2308; 1262 16386 DATABASE maggieprod postgres`

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  encoding LATIN1 does not match locale en_CA.utf8`

`DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.
    Command was: CREATE DATABASE maggieprod WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'LATIN1' TABLESPACE = magdat;`

And using the second, when I try and create the database I get:

`createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding LATIN1 does not match locale en_CA.utf8`

`DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding UTF8.`

So it seems to be that I cannot create a LATIN1 encoding database? Why is that? I am new to locales and encoding and don't know very much about them. I just know that the dump was made off of a LATIN1 database.

The output of `locale` is:

`LANG=en_CA.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.utf8"
LC_ALL=`

And the output of `locale -a` is:

`C
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX`

I don't see LATIN1 in the second command, should I? If so, how would I go about adding it? Is it correct for me to assume that I need to change the locale on my computer? If so, is there a way to do that only for postgreSQL? Also, when I try and open the dump I see a lot of garbage characters, I am assuming this is because of the encoding, how would I look at it properly?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create the database with a locale that matches the encoding, e.g.,

```
createdb -T template0 maggieprod -E LATIN1 --locale=en_CA
```

Since you don't have all locales installed, I guess you are using Debian or Ubuntu.  In that case, call `dpkg-reconfigure locales` or install the `locales-all` package.

Alternatively, create the database with encoding `UTF8`.  As long as all your clients set the client encoding correctly, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Installing the `locales-all` package worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble using the createdb syntax from The_Denominater, so I did it the following way:

```
CREATE DATABASE maggieprod WITH ENCODING = 'LATIN1'
  LC_CTYPE = 'en_CA' LC_COLLATE = 'en_CA'
  TEMPLATE template0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested using the recode command will  transform your database dump to the character set of your choice before you import it into your new database. See this link - http://blog.e-shell.org/134